# Unit testing Module with with $routeParams fails?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm already using test case where I use `$routeParams` without a glicth but I can't make it work on this new test case.

#### Module

I reduce its content to the minimal

```js
"use strict";

angular.module('warehousesModule', ['smart-table', 'services', 'ngRoute'])
.controller('WarehouseEditCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$window', 'API', 'gettextCatalog', 'form',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $window, API, gettextCatalog, form) {
}]);
```

#### Unit test

```js
"use strict";

describe('testModule', function () {
    beforeEach(module('warehousesModule'));

    describe('WarehouseEditCtrl', function () {
        var $scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $routeParams, $controller) {
            $routeParams.compoundId = 3;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('WarehouseEditCtrl', {
                $scope: $scope
            });
        }));

        it('dummy', function () {
        });
    });
});
```

If I change the module and controller to another one (e.g. *productsModule*), it run without error.

#### Error message

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams
    at /home/elopez/projects/tcs_economat/frontend/static/js/vendor.min.js:1
    at r (/home/elopez/projects/tcs_economat/frontend/static/js/vendor.min.js:1)
    at /home/elopez/projects/tcs_economat/frontend/static/js/vendor.min.js:1
    at r (/home/elopez/projects/tcs_economat/frontend/static/js/vendor.min.js:1)
    at i (/home/elopez/projects/tcs_economat/frontend/static/js/vendor.min.js:1)
    at workFn (/home/elopez/projects/tcs_economat/frontend/static_src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2436)
undefined
```

#### Question

Both modules are in my main app, do you see what's the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I find the solution by reviewing my code with a colleague, so peer-review is the solution here !

1. I was missing the `ngRoute` dependency in my module ;

```js
angular.module('warehousesModule', ['smart-table', 'services', 'ngRoute'])
```

2. I forget to rebuild my `*.min.js` after adding the dependency.

```js
gulp default
```